# How to create a public variable in a for loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the result inside my for loop to be displayed at the end of the program

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HELLOwORLD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String answerclient = null;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How long the password should be?");
        int answer = keyboard.nextInt();

        do {
            System.out.print("Generating new password ...\n\n\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < answer; i++)

            {

                int character = (int)(Math.random() * 93 + 33);
                char ch = (char)character;
                System.out.print(ch);


            } 
            System.out.print("\n Generate another password ? (Y/N)\n");
            answerclient = keyboard.next();
        }
        while (answerclient.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

        System.out.print("your new password is" + ch); //this would be the latest password generated before the user said N to Generate another password ? (Y/N).

    }
}
```

I would display at the end the latest password generated before the user said N. Can anybody help me getting that password to show at the end of my program please?

Comment: Just declare your variable outside the loop.

Comment: tried already, the password will show only one character like so https://gyazo.com/0b36f42e258c6a84e7a0b05857240f7e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the length of the password entered by the user is more than 1, then it would be nice to use either a character array or a string to store your password.

I l show it using a string:

Declare a String outside your do/while loop

```
String password = "";
```

Then keep on adding the new generated character to your password.

```
password = password + Character.toString(ch) ;
```

Then print out your password at the end of the code :

```
System.out.println(password) ;
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped me by the way :)

Comment: It will solve the problem of variable but what if user is asking for more number of passwords using do while loop.

Comment: then the variable password needs to be initialised inside the do/while loop.

Answer (score 1):

The variable needs to be declared outside (re: before) your loops in order for it to be accessible outside of said loops. As is, the variable is local to the for loop and will not exist once the loop has completed.

Edit: With regards to your comment -- the declaration needs to be before the do/while as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here the scope of char ch is limited to loop. You need to declare the variable before the loop so that the current value of the variable is accessible from outside of the loop.
The corrected code is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HELLOwORLD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String answerclient = null;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How long the password should be?");
        int answer = keyboard.nextInt();
        List<String> password ;
        int count = 0;
        do {
            System.out.print("Generating new password ...\n\n\n");
            password = new ArrayList<>() ;
            String temppassword = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < answer; i++) {

                int character = (int) (Math.random() * 93 + 33);
                char ch = (char) character;
                System.out.print(ch);
                temppassword = temppassword + ch;

            }
            System.out.print("\n Generate another password ? (Y/N)\n");
            answerclient = keyboard.next();
            password.add(temppassword);
            count++;
        } while (answerclient.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
        for (int i = 0; i < password.size(); i++) {
            if (password.get(i) != null &&  !password.get(i).isEmpty())
                System.out.print("your " + i + " new password is : " + password.get(i) + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to follow as you said and it worked, but at the end of the program the password simply shows only one character, https://gyazo.com/42bba705144a2a67511da5f1d20ff352

Comment: For some reason it would always be the last character of the password

Comment: 4th line in your output console is your generated password.